# Monitoring child node values in Firebase and assigning numerical ranks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have upvote and downvote function's which are performing transactions and correctly manipulating the vote count in my database of sports player names.

Votes are cast as 1's and -1's. Then the math is done to total the player's vote count and put in the database as `votes`

[image: db]

Each time a vote is cast, I would like a function or piece of code to look through all the names in `players` and assign a number to each name depicting their rank among everyone in the database (based on their votes from most to least) (I.e. James has 10 upvotes and 0 down votes (`votes = 10`), he's rank 1. John has 10 upvotes and 1 downvote (`votes = 9`) and is rank 2. If I upvote John, I should refresh the page and see they are tied at 1. This works to a degree with my current code below, but once I start adding more names via the input and do some upvoting, downvoting, and retracting my votes, the voteCount variable gets all whacky and the ranks go way off course. I'm sure there's an easier and or better way to do this.

orderedPlayersRank is an array that sorts the players by `votes`, with the best first and worst last. So my #1 ranked person should always be first in the orderedPlayersRank array.

```
global vars

let prevPlayerVotes = 0
let rankCount = 1
```

---

```
      //RANKING CODE    

      //orderedPlayersRank sorts players from highest votes to lowest

      orderedPlayersRank.map((player) => {
      this.database.child(player.id).transaction(function(player){
      if (player.votes >= prevPlayerVotes) {
          prevPlayerVotes = player.votes
          player.rank = rankCount
      } else if (player.votes < prevPlayerVotes) {
          rankCount++
          player.rank = rankCount
          prevPlayerVotes = player.votes
      } else {
          console.log("Rank calculation error.")
      }
      return player;
   })
})
```

Here's my complete upvote function just for reference. I'm putting the above code in where I have the `//ranking functionality` comment toward the bottom. In that spot, the ranking code is run anytime a valid vote is cast. I would be putting the same code in the downvote function as well.

```
upvotePlayer(playerId) {
const players = this.state.players;

const orderedPlayersRank = _.orderBy(players, ['votes'], ['desc'])
if (this.state.user) {
    let ref = firebase.database().ref('/players/' + playerId + '/voters');
    ref.once('value', snap => {
        var value = snap.val()
        if (value !== null) {
            ref.child(this.uid).once('value', snap => {
                if (snap.val() === 0 || snap.val() == null) {
                    ref.child(this.uid).set(1);
                    this.database.child(playerId).transaction(function(player) {
                        if (player) {
                            player.votes++
                        }
                        return player;
                    })
                } else if (snap.val() === -1) {
                    ref.child(this.uid).set(1);

                    //Added vote balancing 
                    this.database.child(playerId).transaction(function(player) {
                        if (player) {
                            player.votes++
                                player.votes++
                        }
                        return player;
                    })
                } else if (snap.val() === 1) {
                    ref.child(this.uid).set(0);

                    //Added vote balancing
                    this.database.child(playerId).transaction(function(player) {
                        if (player) {
                            player.votes--
                        }
                        return player;
                    })
                } else {
                    console.log("Error in upvoting. snap.val(): " + snap.val())
                }
            })
        } else {
            ref.child(this.uid).set(1);
            this.alertUpVote()
            //Added vote balancing
            this.database.child(playerId).transaction(function(player) {
                if (player) {
                    player.votes++
                        console.log("Player added")
                }
                return player;
            })
        }
    });
//ranking functionality here
} else {
    this.alertNotLoggedIn()
    console.log("Must be logged in to vote.")
}
}
```

As I said, the upvote function is working fine. I'm just looking for some advice on the ranking feature I'm struggling with. I appreciate any help and can supply any other relevant code

Comment: FYI, as [advertised/documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore), Cloud Firestore offers [compound sorting and filtering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) whereas Realtime Database has [limited sorting and filtering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) functionality.  Firestore [Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/update-data#update_data_with_transactions) automatically repeat until they're completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So transactions can be run [multiple times before completion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction) if the data changes before the transaction is resolved. This can cause any variables outside the scope to become out of sync (i.e. `rankCount` and `prevPlayerVotes`). Another reason might be that you are looping over the `orderedPlayersRank` and returning a `Promise` for each call to `transaction`. This will cause `prevPlayerRank` and `rankCount` to be read/modified simultaneously instead of sequentially as I assume you are expecting.

One solution could just be to use `orderByChild('votes')` on the list and use the index paired with checking the previous value to determine rank at display time or set the rank when changes are made to votes (either by Firebase Function, or a watcher).

Ex. (Firebase Function)

```
export var rank = functions.database.ref('players/{playerId}/votes')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  // list by 'votes' in ascending order
  var orderedListRef = change.after.ref.root.child('players').orderByChild('votes')
  var oldVotes = change.before.val()
  var newVotes = change.after.val()
  var notChanged = 0
  var changeRank = 0
  // went higher in the list so bump every player passed by 1
  if (newVotes > oldVotes) {
    // Range: [oldVotes, newVotes]
    orderedListRef = orderedListRef.startAt(oldVotes).endAt(newVotes)
    changeRank = 1
    notChanged = newVotes
  } else {// went lower in the list so bump every player passed by -1
    // Range: [newVotes, oldVotes]
    orderedListRef = orderedListRef.startAt(newVotes).endAt(oldVotes)
    changeRank = -1
    notChanged = oldVotes
  }
  return orderedListRef.once('value')
  .then((ss) => {
    var promises = []
    var playersPassed = 0
    // IMPORTANT: must use `forEach` to ensure proper order
    ss.forEach((playerSS) => {
      if (playerSS.key === context.params.playerId) {
        return
      }
      playersPassed += 1
      if (playerSS.child('votes').val() === notChanged) {
        return
      }
      // use transaction to ensure proper number of bumps if multiple changes at once
      promises.push(playerSS.child('rank').ref.transaction((rank) => {
        return rank + changeRank
      }))
    })
    // use transaction to adjust rank by players passed
    promises.push(change.before.ref.parent.child('rank')
    .transaction((rank) => {
      return rank - playersPassed * changeRank
    }))
    return Promise.all(promises)
  })
})
```

Initialization example

```
export var initRank = functions.database.ref('players/{playerId}/votes')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  // list by 'votes' in ascending order
  return Promise.all([
    snapshot.ref.root
      .child('players')
      .orderByChild('votes')
      .startAt(snapshot.val())
      .once('value')
      .then((ss) => {
        return snapshot.ref.parent.child('rank').transaction((rank) => {
          if (rank) {
            return rank + ss.numChildren
          }
          return ss.numChildren
        })
      }),
    snapshot.ref.root
      .child('players')
      .orderByChild('votes')
      .endAt(snapshot.val()-1)
      .once('value')
      .then((ss) => {
        var promises = []
        ss.forEach((playerSS) => {
          promises.push(playerSS.child('rank').ref.transaction((rank) => {
            if (rank) {
              return rank + 1
            }
          })
        })
        return Promise.all(promises)
      })
  ])
})
```

With this approach, you will need to set the rank of newly created players to the highest rank. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've read through and I understand what's going on for the most part. I have not used Firebase functions previously. I just did the basic firebase function setup and I see the folder and functions index.js in my project. I threw a few console.logs in there to see if it ever runs and I'm not seeing it do so. Am I missing something? I built and deployed it. Thanks again

Comment: Are you on the correct plan for Firebase functions? Also, this watches updates to a player's votes. You might also want to make sure the path it is watching is correct.

Comment: @idlehand Did you export the function? If you look in your console (https://console.firebase.google.com/project/<project-id>/functions/list), do you see "rank" listed?

Comment: I am on Spark, which looks to have some functions capability, I could be wrong though. I added an export to rank (exports.rank). When I build, I see rank being built under functions, but i don't ever see it make it to my console.

Comment: @idlehand So you see "functions[rank]: Successful..." when you do `firebase deploy --only functions`, but the function isn't listed in the Firebase Functions console? Are you deploying to the correct project? (I usually have multiple Firebase projects for one app, i.e. dev, test, prod)

Comment: The `firebase deploy --only functions` did work that time, thanks. It's coming up in the console and is changing the rank number on the app and in firebase. The current rank code is off a bit as well, but I'll see if I can make any progress with it. When I enter the first player in (no one in the database) it seems to start them off at -1, and then when I add another, they go to -2, so on. Might be something minor

Comment: Yeah this ranking function works for when votes change, but you will need to handle the edge cases outside of this function. That will depend on how you handle voting (i.e. can a player have negative votes). Also, what is a player's rank when they have no votes of any kind. Depending on those conditions, the above example might need to be tweaked to fit your specific use-case.

Comment: Thanks! When I submit a new player to the database via input box, the `votes` and `rank` are set to 0. The `votes` for the new player are then immediately changed to a 1 or -1, depending if the up or downvote button was pressed on the input box. So when I add the first player to the database via the upvote, he for a split second is rank 0, then immediate goes to -1. If I added a second via downvote, he goes to rank 0, which is semi right, however the first should be a 1, and the second player should be rank 2. Is there something I'm missing to make sure the top player is never negative rank?

Comment: So you need to initialize the `rank` when the player is created. That will depend on whether a player can have negative votes. I'll update the answer to include the init section, but it won't be a very scalable solution.